# Running Python Scripts in Command Line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, scripting

I am trying to run a script I wrote and I hope to distribute. Each time I run outside of an activated virtual environment "No module named", I guess it is because it has some dependencies that are not in-built. How do I overcome this issue ?

Comment: Show your script and the error message of your command pls

Comment: The script works. The error message it shows on the command line occurs when a virtual environment is not activated, the error "no module .....  found".  I can install all the dependencies to my python library and it works but I plan to distribute this script that will be inconvenient for whoever uses it.

Comment: If, by "distribute", you mean the eventual user will run something like `pip install your_cool_script`, then the distribution package will ensure that the necessary modules are installed at that time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install that modules outside the virtual environment that is directly in the system.

And If you want to distribute your script then add all of your required modules in requirements.txt file and provide this file to another user along your script and then just run this command to install the modules:-

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

OR

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a requirements file, those who want to use your project can run the command provided by Dinky Arora to get the required packages.

I recommend downloading [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) which helps your generate requirement files by running the following command :

```
pip install pipreqs
```

Then run :

```
pipreqs /path/to/project
```

To generate a requirements file.

Note : You can also use freeze, it does the same job.
Moreover, you could generate a setup.py to install your python project + all its dependencies.

Comment: I am aware of this method. I was juts wondering if there was a way when they run the script and the script detects missing packages and installs them first before going on.